# Not Equal to condition in codeigniter is not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Not equal to condition is not working in my sql query of codeigniter.
I also tried with <> but this also not working please some one help to solve this.
output is displaying with equal to condition

```
 $result = $this->db->query("select a.user_email  from users as a, result as b where b.exam_id = '".$exam_id."' and a.user_id  != b.user_id  and  a.active =  1 and a.user_role_id != 1 group by a.user_id")
->result();
```

Comment: Not working means?? And have you got any error???

Comment: Your query may be wrong. post more code

Comment: There is some different problem.It is not due to (!=) sign. Not equal to works in Codeigniter query very well and i use this every time i need.Try running this query in phpmyadmin sql pannel and debug.

Comment: it is not taking a.user_id  != b.user_id  condition instead it is displaying results of  a.user_id  = b.user_id

Comment: i have checked in phpmyadmin also it is showing the same results

Comment: Are you trying to find Users without a record in Result? If so, why not use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: exactly Michael O'Brien.Please check this query using NOT EXISTS $result = $this->db->query("select a.user_email  from users as a, result as b where b.exam_id = '".$exam_id."' and not exists('b.user_id')  and  a.active = 1 and a.user_role_id != 1 group by a.user_id")
->result();

Comment: Thansks every 1, especially Michael O'Brien your idea helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every1 one for your suggestions. here is the correct query

```
select * from users 
where user_id not in (select user_id from result  where exam_id = '".$exam_id."')  and  active = 1 and user_role_id != 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this as you query is not clearly understandable to the compiler that's why it's giving wrong output.

```
$query="select a.user_email  "
        . "from users as a, result as b "
        . "where b.exam_id = '".$exam_id."'"
        ."a.active =  1 and"
        . "(a.user_id  != b.user_id)  "
        . "and "
        . "(a.user_role_id != 1 group by a.user_id)"
```